Alternatives to Junction Objects for Managing Class-Student Relationships in Salesforce
I'm working on a Salesforce project to manage the relationship between Students and Classes, where each student can be enrolled in multiple classes. Currently, we're using a Class Link junction object to connect the Student and Class records. However, this setup is creating an overload of data and records.
To simplify the model, I'm exploring ways to eliminate the Class Link object and directly link Students to multiple Classes, while still maintaining the same functionality without adding too much complexity.
Any suggestions on the best approach for this what would be the best alternative?

There is no clean way to do this and be scalable. Storing collections of IDs in text fields is non-portable, non-reportable and prone to issues where class lists can be updated concurrently by multiple users. Honestly, do not try to "simplify" the object model to remove the junction object; you will cause problems for yourself.

BTW, welcome to SFSE. Please note that we don't tend to answer this sort of opinion-based question. Take a look at How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour].

@PhilW Thanks for the input . I see the issues with scalability and reporting using text fields. However, my concern is the large number of records created by the Class Link junction object. I mainly need to search for Classes and display the Students linked to them, and the Students are also linked elsewhere on an answer response. Is there really no alternative for managing this without generating so much data? I'm hoping to find a more efficient solution that reduces the record count while maintaining functionality

IMO, this is the way that Salesforce expects this sort of scenario to be modelled. Yes, you consume 2K the database per junction object, and that can be problematic, but to take an alternative "home grown" approach, such as using a long text area field to hold the student IDs, has a lot of disadvantages and I couldn't recommend it. If you want to discuss this further, I suggest raising it on the trailblazer forums instead (since those cater to more opinion-based questions or more general questions).

I think such comments make a perfectly useful answer. Much better than a series of comments. I don't believe this question is likely to lead to opinion based answers and vote to keep it open.
